# Read Google docs body with the get function in c#

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I want to be able to print the body of a google docs in the console using c#.

I am able to print the title using this code

```
DocumentsResource.GetRequest request = service.Documents.Get(documentId);
Document doc = request.Execute();        
                     
Console.WriteLine(doc.Title);
```

but I am unable to do the same thing with the body of the text using this code

```
DocumentsResource.GetRequest request = service.Documents.Get(documentId);
Document doc = request.Execute();        
                     
Console.WriteLine(doc.Body);
```

The output is `Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Body`.

What is the problem with the code and what should I change ?

Comment: The output looks like the class name, which probably means you need to iterate over elements of Body in a loop and output multiple lines.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This is what I've tried.
If i use the `Console.WriteLine(doc.Body.Content.Count);` , I get 2 as the output

then if I use a foreach loop to print every element of `doc.Body.Content`. I get 
`Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.StructuralElement
Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.StructuralElement`

Comment: You'll probably need to look up the google api documentation.  You will need to at least get to something that represents a row if you're going to use Console.WriteLine.  Maybe use some nested foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to extract the data out of the `body` object.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on the [Document Resource](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document), the `body` is an object containing more than just a string of data:

```
{
  "documentId": string,
  "title": string,
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {
        "startIndex": integer,
        "endIndex": integer,
        "paragraph": {
          object (Paragraph)
        },
        "sectionBreak": {
          object (SectionBreak)
        },
        "table": {
          object (Table)
        },
        "tableOfContents": {
          object (TableOfContents)
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

The Document resource goes quite a few layers deep, so depending on what information you are trying to extract from the Body, you will have to reference this directly - something like `doc.Body.Content[0].Paragraph.Elements[0].TextRun.Content` - but this will highly depend on what your document contains.

You can also try viewing the whole object with by serialising the object with the [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) as recommended by Microsoft.

#### References:

- [REST Resource: documents | Google Docs API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document)
- [JavaScriptSerializer Class (System.Web.Script.Serialization) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)